# Запрос на добавление в две таблицы

Tags: sql

Нужно добавить данные в две связаные таблицы одним запросом.  Делаю конструктором, но там можно добавить только в одну таблицу, а в SQL  я  - ноль!
Помогите!

Comment: Почему именно одним? А не двумя в одной транзакции?

Answer (score 1):

Insert into table1 values(...); Insert into table2 values(..., linked_key=@@identity); ? а что за СУБД?